# Preventing SQL injection when setting a sqldatasource select statement in ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, code-injection

I have a quick question with regards to preventing SQL injection in my application.

Two different features of my web application use textboxes that a user can use to search for items from a MSSQL database. This information is displayed in a GridView.

I create the queries by using this method:

```
sqldatasource.SelectCommand = "SELECT x from x where this_id LIKE '%" + txtbox.Text + "%' ORDER BY x ASC";
```

Obviously taking user input and entering it straight into a query like this will open it up to basic SQL injection. Please could someone explain how I can parametrise this to prevent SQL injection in my application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx

Comment: Mike91: There are two ways to ask this question. The first way is "I'm lazy. Can someone please post a link to the documentation for parameterized queries... or better still - just write my code for me?". The second way is "I've read the documentation and I understand the principles, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this query: "...". I tried this: "..." but it gave this error: "...". Any idea how to fix this?". Which question do you think is more likely to attract answers?

Comment: +1 for having the good sense to ask.  I really, ***really*** wish more people did.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. In the end I used this from the MSDN site on parametrised queries:

```
    GetSubInfo.SelectParameters.Add("xparam", txtbox.Text);
    GetSubInfo.SelectCommand = "SELECT x from x where x_id LIKE @xparam ORDER BY x ASC";
```

This is very similar to Hogan's answer, with slightly different syntax. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

```
sqldatasource.SelectCommand = @"SELECT x from x where this_id LIKE @inText ORDER BY x ASC";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inText", "%" + txtbox.Text + "%");
```

Note, you are going to be in for pain if you start a `LIKE` with a wildcard.  A big table will be sad and go slowly.

Answer (score 0):

One (not very good, but better than nothing) way is to sanitize the contents of txtBox.Text, and then use the sanitized result.

```
sqlsource.SelectCommand = "SELECT x from x where this_id LIKE '%" + SanitizedString(txtBox.Text) + "%';";

// ... codes ...

private string SanitizedString(string given)
{
   string sanitized = given.Replace(";", string.Empty);
   sanitized = sanitized.Replace("--", string.Empty);
   // ... ad nauseum, conditions galore ...

   return sanitized;
}
```

...However, that's VERY labor intensive.

The thing to do would be to use a bind variable in the form of a stored procedure.  From what I can see, you could bind your filter txtbox.Text condition, and then just pass that in.

The query would be simple enough on the db, something like:

```
SELECT x from X where this_id LIKE :filter ORDER BY x ASC
```

To call it, you would need to research how MSSQL communicates with stored procedures.

Bind variables make your code thoroughly SQL-injection-proof.  *Love bind variables*, for they will love you.  And evil hax0rs will not.

Comment: This has nothing to do with parameterised queries.

Comment: `:filter` - this looks like mysql, the question says sqlserver.

Comment: @Dems: Perhaps I misunderstood, but in the original post, the poster is asking about ways to avoid SQL injection.  Parameterized queries are one way to avoid the problem of SQL injection.  Further, at the end of the question, the OP writes:

"Please could someone explain how I can parametrise this to prevent SQL injection in my application?"

So, yes, my answer is relevant to the question.

Comment: @Hogan: You're right - my apologies.  SQL Server uses @ instead of : for parameter names.  I also omitted the declaration of the bind variable as well.